# How can I get the custom ID from interactionCreate for buttons?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Is it possible to get the custom ID from interactionCreate for buttons?

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        // I want to get the CustomId of the button that was pressed here.
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be changed to this and it can be obtained

```
client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        const btn_id = interaction.customId;
        //btn_id = your button id
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `.customId`

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        // interaction.customId;
    }
})
```

[ButtonInteraction#customId](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=customId)